# Can transitive verb be followed by prep?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

There is an example:

[from here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate)

> This attribute evaluates to true.

Here, **evaluate** is a transitive verb, *vt* followed by a prep, is it correct?

Can transitive verb be followed by prep?

Comment: What does the sentence mean?

Comment: *His wealth **amounts to** nothing* looks like the same basic form to me. But are ***evaluate*** and ***amount*** true "transitive" verbs here? Phrasal verbs or copulas, perhaps?

Comment: @BillJ I add source.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Here, **amount** is *vi*, and **evaluate** could only be *vt*. So, you sentence is normal for me.

Comment: I'm not really interested in the terminology of "non-obvious" referents, but it seems to me ***to evauate to, to amount to, to equate to, to correspond to,...*** are all syntactically and semantically near-equivalents. If that doesn't help you, I have nothing further to offer.

Comment: Here, "evaluate" is ***intransitive***. It has no object, other than the indirect object of the preposition "to"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb "evaluate" can be used transitively and intransitively, with related but different meanings.

You can say "I evaluate the expression"  or "The expression evaluates".  The role played by the object in the transitive form is that played by the subject in the intransitive form.  In this way the verb "evaluate" is similar to verbs like "open":  "I open the door" / "The door opens".

In the intransitive form, the (mandatory?) prepositional phrase gives the result of the evaluation.

Comment: Where do you get this **evaluate** can be used intransitively? I look up this word, can only get info *vt*.

Comment: I get it from the sentence "This expression evaluates to false".  This is an intransitive verb since there is no direct object.  The analogy with "open" is quite good.  You can say "This door opens to the garden"

Comment: So, conclusion is: this sentence is correct and **evaluate** is intransitive verb in the sentence and intransitive verbs can't followed by prep. Is my understanding right?

Comment: My analysis is that evaluate is being used as an intransitive verb.  It is followed by a prepositional phrase "to true".

Comment: I correct one thing: the word *intransitive* should be *transitive* in last reply. I have understanded what you mean. I express my doubt further here: Its correct if evaluate can be used intransitively, but is it correct if it can't, and is the rule applied well for other similar verbs?

Comment: In the sentence "The expression evaluates to true", the verb evaluate is being used as an **intransitive** verb.  It is not followed by a direct object.  See also "ergative verbs".

Comment: Then, how about this **The expression evaluated true** and **The expression evaluated to true**, these both are correct? The three sentences are equivalent?

Comment: "The expression evaluated true" That would be even odder, but it appears to be "evaluated" used as a linking verb with an adjective complement.

Answer (score 0):

There are verbs in English, so-called phrasal verbs, that incorporate a preposition. They are similar to separable verbs in German.

Under normal circumstances, I’d suggest that “evaluate to” is such a verb. But a transitive verb or a preposition requires an object, which is a noun or pronoun. And, under normal circumstances, “true” is an adjective. No wonder you are confused.

Your example comes from the world of computers, which is notorious for weird constructions. I lived in that world for a number of years. One reason for the weirdness is that many people in that world are not attuned to complex social processes such as language. The other reason is that thinking about computers is psychologically strange. An engineer designed a bunch of circuits that operate in absolutely predictable ways. A programmer designed a set of procedures to make those circuits respond in certain ways. And then the computer gave certain results. Is the computer a subject or an object? Grammar scratches its head. From one perspective, a computer is a passive object which does exactly what people have forced it to do. From another perspective, it is an entity performing tasks rapidly and flawlessly without any apparent human intervention.

So let’s translate your phrase,

> If the attribute is evaluated as true

means simultaneously

> if the condition in which we are interested is true, then …

and

> if the program evaluates the data provided and as a consequence sets a specific Boolean variable to the value of one (which value is named “True” in Boolean algebra), then …

Two things are going on: a decision as to whether a condition is true and a corresponding set of physical processes (evaluation and assignment of values) inside the computer. The statement abbreviates and conflates the two into a mess understandable to people who deal with this kind of language all the time.

In short, the jargon of computer science is a horrible guide to normal English usage, and standard grammatical analysis will not help you construe it.

Comment: Thank your for detailed answer. You give me more tech explanations but I rather expect grammer explanation.